# Google map route not able to get for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

When i find the route between the two latitude and longitude values in the Google map(Get direction)show it correctly but when i used in the mobile application in android it only shows the marker of the destination, it doesn't shows the route correctly i don't know why it is happening?

Comment: what method you are using to display route on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Google Maps in my application using following code and it works fine for me.

**saddr = source address (latitude & longitude / you can also pass address string like New York)**

**daddr = destination address (latitude & longitude / you can also pass address string like India)**

```
public void showDirections(View view) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitude + "," + longitude + "&daddr=" + latitude + "," + longitude));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Hope this will help you also.